# Want to understand array literals inside a string declaration in typescript, Angular ngrx/store

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, namespaces, ngrx-store

While reading a tutorial in youtube on ngrx/store, I came across the below syntax:

```
export const LOAD_PIZZAS = '[Products] Load Pizzas';
```

Could anyone explain the meaning of this assignment statement. Or anyhelp is highly appreciated. Link: https://youtu.be/5JzOlB5eNDA

Comment: Looks like a plain string to me.

Answer (score 0):

```
export const LOAD_PIZZAS = '[Products] Load Pizzas';
```

The `export` means you are using modules -- there are several format modules out there.  That string will be exported into the module.

`const` assigns a value.  There are dozens of references on how `const` varies from `var`.

The rest is a standard string assignment.